# Do I need NG-IF / NG-SWITCH or NG-SHOW & NG-HIDE?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm experiencing a lot of frustration with this one because I just don't know which method I should use, below is the basic setup.

I want to show the current state of a movie, based on the states of the movie I want to have different message in the DOM, a movie can have 3 different states.
Note: **The movies are stored in a JSON file and are all displayed on 1 page.**

- State 1.

  Movie released: **true** 
  Movie in theaters: **true**

  *User-text: "In theaters now!"*
- State2.

  Movie release: **true** 
  Movie in theaters: **false**

  *User-text: "Buy now!" (The buy link will be included in the movie
  object)*
- State 3.

  Movie release: **false**
  Movie in theaters: **false**

  *User-text: **SHOW RELEASE DATE HERE***

So it's:  true,true || true,false || false false.

**HTML CODE.**

```
   <div class="ui blue ribbon label" ng-if="vm.getRelease(movie)">
   <i class="film icon"></i> {{vm.movieStatus}}
  </div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
        function getRelease(movie){
        if(movie.released && movie.inTheaters){
            vm.movieStatus = "In Theaters now!";
            return true
        } else {
            return 
        }
    }
```

**JSON OBJECT**

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Captain America: Civil War",
    "yay": 500365,
    "nay": 14357,
    "releaseYear": 2016,
    "releaseDate": "27-4-2016",
    "inTheaters": true,
    "released": true,
    "buyNow": "",
    "imdbUrl": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498820/",
    "image_url": "http://cityplusme.com/images/CaptainAmericaCivilWar.jpg",
    "description": "Political interference in the Avengers' activities causes a rift between former allies Captain America and Iron Man.",
    "trailer": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKrVegVI0Us"
},
```

This works fine and shows ***"In Theaters now!"***, the only problem is now that I need use more conditions and change the vm.movieStatus based on them.
I've tried to work with a lot of different things but I can't seem to work it out.

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: When you use ng-if items that aren't visible are actually removed from the DOM, which in general is what you want to do for optimal performance and resource utilization. I'd suggest posting what is not working in order to get more helpful answers. Calling a function like you are from ng-if is perfectly acceptable, and generally preferred for more complex logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, `ngIf` directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an `{expression}`. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise, a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

You need to decide whether you want to keep the other state's elements in the DOM and just hide them(using CSS, which is what ngShow/ngHide does) or remove the elements from the DOM altogether (which is what `ngIf` would do).

The expression you use will be like `ng-if="movie.released && movie.inTheaters"` or similar.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out!